# C++ basic array assignment is not working

Tags: c++

So I have a function

```
f(int D[],int A[],int len){ 
   for(int k = 0; k < len; k++)
      D[k] = A[k];
```

and if I output `D` the numbers are all wrong. The function `f` is called with `D` initialised as `int* D = new int[100000];` in the `main` function and `A` is all good because I output it in the function and it looks ok. So... can't understand where the problem is... I also tried `memcpy(D+k,A+k,sizeof(int));` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could format your paragraph for readability, ie highlight your code, or put it on separate lines, etc.  All the interspersed code in the same font esp is hard to make out. It's in your own interest, the more readable your post, the more people will read it, and hopefully help :)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make `A` and `D` `std::vector`s, and do the copy with `D = A;`?

Comment: The problem isn't in this code, so it must be in the calling code.  Hence the request for a short, self-contained, complete, compilable example.  You've missed the return type of the function.  Since you're using `new`, this isn't C, either.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop works perfectly. The problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Here is an example program which copies the data in three different ways: a `for` loop, `memcpy`, and `std::copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void copy1(int D[], int A[], int len) {
  for(int k = 0; k < len; k++)
    D[k] = A[k];
}

void copy2(int D[], int A[], int len) {
  std::memcpy(D, A, len*sizeof(int));
}

void copy3(int D[], int A[], int len) {
  std::copy(A, A+len, D);
}

int main () {
  int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  int *d = new int[10];

  std::ostream_iterator<int> out(std::cout, ",");

  // First, print the initial values
  std::copy(d, d+10, out);
  std::cout << "\n";

  // Next do the copies and print the values again
  copy1(d, a, 10);
  std::copy(d, d+10, out);
  std::cout << "\n";

  copy2(d, a, 10);
  std::copy(d, d+10, out);
  std::cout << "\n";

  copy3(d, a, 10);
  std::copy(d, d+10, out);
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The output I get is:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in debugger and see if you do not have garbage in `A[]` in the first place (it could go wrong after function call).  Also I suggest you pass reference (like `int & D[]` and `const int & A[]` — `const` to prevent altering of `A`).

Comment: `int & D[]` and `const int & A[]` are not valid constructs -- you can't have arrays of references.

Comment: A is ok because I print it and it's ok !

Answer (score 0):

Start with a minimal working example such as the following, then integrate your other code into it until something breaks. That’ll be the source of your error. Without more information, this is pretty much all I can tell you; when you encounter wrong values in a C++ program, you’re likely reading from an uninitialised variable. I suggest you try stepping through your program in a debugger such as GDB.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void f(int D[], const int A[], int len){ 
   for(int k = 0; k < len; k++)
      D[k] = A[k];
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  int D[5];
  f(D, A, 5);
  std::copy(A, A + 5, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << '\n';
  std::copy(D, D + 5, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  return 0;
}
```

Unless you have a very good reason to do so, prefer `std::vector` and `std::array` over raw arrays. Learning how arrays and pointers work is a good reason to use them, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are passing in a pointer to an array
int* D = new int[100000];

however, your function takes two integer arrays, which is not the same as a pointer to an array.

Here's a SSCCE of a snippet that behaves like you want it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int * d, int * a, int length){
    for(int k = 0; k < length; k++){
            d[k] = a[k];
    }
}

int main() {
    int* a = new int[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){a[i] = i;}
    int* d = new int[9];
    f(d, a, 9);

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            cout << d[i] << " ";
    }
}
```